# How to add org-babel-execute function for plantuml?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, package-repositories

I installed "PlantUML Mode for Emacs" using Melpa successfully, and I am able to switch to Plantuml-mode.  However, when I try to evaluate code with `C-c C-c`, inside of org-mode, I get the error:

```
org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for plantuml!
```

How do I add this?

Comment: I think that the backend comes with `plantuml-mode`, do you have it installed?

Comment: @wvxvw  I believe so, at least I know I can swtich to plantuml-mode

Comment: If you look in your `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org` or equivalent place where you stored your Org mode sources, do you have `ob-plantuml.elc`, `ob-plantuml.el.gz` or similar file in there? If so, will adding `(require 'ob-plantuml)` to your init file (and evaluation) solve the problem?

Comment: @wvxvw  That fixed it, thanks a lot!   (I added the require to my init file)

Comment: Hm... technically, just adding `plantuml` to `org-babel-load-languages` should've worked. Wait, did you actually add `plantuml` to this variable? Something like: `(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((plantuml . t)))`

Comment: @wvxvw  All I did was add `(require 'ob-plantuml)` to my init.el file.  I did not add  plantuml to the babel-load-languages variable (maybe it was done by melpa's get package?)

Comment: Nope, MELPA wouldn't do this. It's for the user to decide which languages need to be enabled (automatically enabling them would be a security risk). However, enabling them should also require them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the list of languages you want to use with org-babel inside the with-eval-after-load block

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((ruby . t)
(plantuml . t)
)))
```